# Grails spring security rest plugin's filter chain not working as expected

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

I am using grails version 2.5.4 and spring security rest plugin version 1.5.4.
I have added filter chain map in my config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

It's works but when I fetch springSecurityServie's principle object it provides me anonymous user

but it works fine when I put this as filter chain

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',  // Stateless chain
        '/stateful/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

Comment: try adding `-anonymousAuthenticationFilter` in the `'/api/**'`

Comment: added it doesn't work either